# How to arrange a text in the particular order?

Tags: html, css

i have one paragraph tag which contains some data , i want to arrange the text in the following order by using html and css, please help me to acheive this thing..

`Expected format`

```
========================================
  ===================================
    ===============================
       ========================
           ================
```

`index.html`

```
<p class="stylish-txt"> assume some dummy data </p>
```

Comment: `text-align: center;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put these p elements in a container and make it text-align: center.

Or, you can put the same in the element itself. It works too.

But you will need multiple p elements to achieve this.

Comment: Or just `<br/>`